# phased array beam width spread as beam scans off boresite

Tags: antenna

What is the approximate phased array beam width spread  as beam scans off bore site? Assume nominal scan space of 120 deg Azimuth by 90 deg Elevation, ie +/- 60 by +/- 45. Array elements are all uniform, and uniformly spaced.

Comment: Anything with "Assume" in it is ... assumed ... to be homework. We don't do that for you, but you can show us your working and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

To a first approximation, the beam width will increase as 1/Cos of the angle off-axis.